# Q Promise resolve/reject logic - why isn't promise returned as rejected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

New to promises, trying to understand the logic flow. Thought I understood until I started to insert errors to test. In the example below, when I comment out the 3rd line, why doesn't Reject get returned in the promise?

```js
var Q = require( "q" )

var getInstallBase = function() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
 //var IBdata = 'temp IBdata'; // <------comment out so IBdata not defined
     if (IBdata){
            resolve(IBdata); // State will be fulfilled
        } else {
     reject("error getting IBdata"); // State will be rejected             
        }
     });
}

var mungeIt = function(IBdata){
    return new Q.Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  // get insight from data
  console.log('IBdata = ' + IBdata);
  var insight = 'temp insight';
        if (insight){
            resolve(insight); // State will be fulfilled
        } else {
            reject("error getting insight"); // State will be rejected
        }
    })
}

var postResults = function(insight) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  console.log('insight = ' + insight);
  // post result
  var objectID = '12345';
  if (objectID){
   setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('done waiting');
    resolve(objectID);
   }, 2000);
    // State will be fulfilled
  } else {
   reject("error posting insight to object store"); // State will be rejected
  }
 });
};

(function extractInsightCycle() {
 getInstallBase().then(mungeIt).then(postResults).then(function(objectID) {
  console.log('object successfully posted, ID: ' + objectID)
  extractInsightCycle();
 }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('something went wrong', error);
  extractInsightCycle();
 })
} )();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*Reject doesn't get returned in the promise*"? Doesn't the `catch` callback execute?

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zutotuvomo/edit?js,console

It contains a simplified version of your code, and as you can see, the promise returned from `getInstallBase` indeed rejects.

Probably something else in your code makes it look like it did not reject.

**EDIT:**

I took another look at the code, and this is what happens - the rejected promise is being caught by:

```
function(error) {
    console.log('something went wrong', error);
    extractInsightCycle();
}
```

Which calls the `extractInsightCycle` which is the function that's initiating the whole process, and this causes an infinite loop (endless recursion actually).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're right it is something else that makes it look like it doesn't reject - and it boils down to my lack of understanding. Here's what I don't get:

Comment: 1) I expected to see "error getting IBdata" returned and shown somewhere, why doesn't it?

Comment: 3) All errors get caught, but you can completely remove the `else {
            reject("error getting insight"); 
        }`, and you get the same result as when it is there, so what's the point?

Comment: If you console.log('show me') in the 'else' right before the reject, it doesn't get logged to the console - such as `if (insight){
            resolve(insight); // State will be fulfilled
        } else {
            reject("error getting insight"); 
        }`. Why not?